# C# WPF Fire Event After Custrom Controls fully displayed

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I'm trying to figure out how to fire an event after my controls have been displayed. For Example.

```
    private void MainWindow_Ready(object sender, DataSet e)
    {
            foreach (table in e.Tables)
            {
                control = new LeagueControl(table);
                SP1.Children.Add(control);
            }
        });
    }

    void SomeMethod()
    {

    }
```

So after the controls I add to SP1 are actually showing in my Window I want to run the method SomeMethod();

Doing this I was able to get what I needed.

```
            int count = 0;
            foreach (DataTable table in e.Tables)
            {
                count++;
                control = new LeagueControl(table);
                SP1.Children.Add(control);
                if (count == e.Tables.Count)
                {
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, new Action(() =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("X");
                    }));
                }
            }
```

Really though, It's working for me, but are there better ways? I'm not to sure why it works either maybe somebody can elaborate, thanks.

Comment: I tried to use your answer Lake Chan but the delegate function runs the method before the controls are actually showing on my window. So no good but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a delegate function as a eventHandler to the Loaded event.

**Code:**

```
control.Loaded += delegate(object o, RoutedEventArgs e){
    SomeMethod();
}
```

Comment: see this delegate function runs my method before the controls I add to SP1 are showing so this unfortunately wont help.